# compile a single ASP.NET (.aspx) page from the command line

Tags: asp.net, command-line, scripting

I have a Perl script that calls aspnet_compiler.exe to compile a large ASP.NET website.  The problem is that it takes very long to run.  Is there any way to compile just a single .aspx file from the command line? (I think that would suit the needs of my script)  It seems that all aspnet_compiler.exe can do is compile at a directory level.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at batched compilation (its configurable in the web.config)

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you are using Perl for this? Have you looked at MSBUILD?

http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-videos/video-394.aspx